# Angle of intersection between

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Calculate the angle of intersection between the functions $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ at the point $1.001, 1.9167$ where:

$g(x)=0.4 ln⁡((10(x-1))+3.88623$

and

$f(x)= \sqrt {x-1} + 1.9427$

Comment: Please do not use tags you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\tan a = g'(x)$ and $\tan b = f'(x).$

Let $c = a - b.$

Then $\tan c = \tan (a - b) = \frac{\tan a - \tan b}{1 + \tan a \tan b}.$

Comment: Thank you! solved for 0.607 radians